# How to check change event fired or not in the jquery

Tags: jquery

How to check my change event fired or not if its fird I need send true if not i need to send false..

```
$("#selectid").change(function(){
});
```

I need to check this event is fired or not..?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is related to your other question. I updated my answer in that one since you asked about it there, but I guess I'll post the answer here too.

One way to track which form elements were modified would be through `.data()`.

```
var array;

$("#fieldset").change(function(event) {
    $(event.target).data('changed',true);
});

$("form").submit(function() {
    array = $(this).find("input, select,textarea").map(function() {
        var $th = $(this);
        if( $th.data('changed') ) return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    alert(array);
    return false;
});​
```

Comment: thanks patrick, the problme is I have submit button in one view and these fielset editable is in other view..

Comment: @rockers - When you say "view", do you mean a different page, or just a different part of the current page?

Answer (score 1):

```
var didF=false;

$("#selectid").change(function(){
   didF=true;
});

...

if (didF) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: That won't really work because you're checking the value of `didF` immediately after binding the callback.

Comment: No, ... occurs immediately after binding the callback. if occurs wherever the check needs to be made.

Answer (score 1):

The line of code you included in your question binds a function (a callback or handler) to the `change` event of the element with ID `selectid`. Are you trying to determine if your callback fires?

If that's the case, there are a variety of options. If you're using Firebug or another debugger, you can either put a breakpoint somewhere in your callback. You can also use the `debugger;` keyword to "hardcode" a breakpoint into a specific location, like this:

```
$("#selectid").change(function(){
    debugger;
});
```

The most rudimentary way to see when your callback fires is to use an `alert` in place of the debugger statement:

```
$("#selectid").change(function(){
    alert("It fired!";
});
```

I'm not sure what you mean about "sending true or false."

Comment: I need to check in document.ready funtion wheather any changed are made to selectid or not?

Comment: The document ready event fires only once per page, and it will generally fire before the user can interact with your page. So, you will really never see a user-induced `change` event fire within a document ready handler. Could you explain in any more detail what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably *check* if an event has fired from outside the handler.

I assume you're looking for something such as:

```
var changed = false;

$("#selectid").change(function(){
    changed = true;
});

if (changed) {
    doSomething();
} else {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

But, unless the user is insanely fast (and the browser isn't faster still), the `if` will be evaluated ***long*** before the `change` handler function is actually called. So, `doSomethingElse` will be called 99.99999999999999% of the time.

However, you can factor that same human input delay into your approach. Rather than post-testing for changes, assume from the start that no changes have occurred. Then, contain your `true` script in the `change` handler. But, the key is to handle all dependencies of the change event within the handler.

```
prepareWithoutChanges();

$("#selectid").change(function(){
    handleChange();
    triggerOtherDependencies();
});
```

But, I'm afraid, without knowing what you need to accomplish, I can't be anymore specific than this.